# Populating a 2D array with every possible combination of 3 math operators

Tags: java, arrays, logic

I want to build a 2D array that can hold every 3 item combination of the four math operators (+-*/)
The array is supposed to look something like this

[-, - , -]

[-, *, *]

[-, /, /]

 

... 

[/, *, *]

[/, /, /]

However I'm running into some problems. My code, when just printing the combinations, is printing each of the combinations 3 times each. Second, I'm not too sure how to get each operator into its place in the array.

Here's my code

```
String[][] allOps = new String[27][3];
    int count = 1;

    String[] ops = new String[] {"+","-","*","/"};
    for (int x=1;x<4;x++) 
    { 
        for (int y=1;y<4;y++)  
        {
            for (int z=1;z<4;z++)
            {


                //System.out.println(ops[x] + " " + ops[y] + " " + ops[z] + " " + count);
                //count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to  get each operator in it's specific place ([ * ][ * ] [ * ]) using a for loop?

Comment: Arrays are 0-indexed. Your indexes in the `for` loops should start from 0.

Comment: You have a typo. The third value should be using `ops[z]` instead of `ops[y]`. [It works fine](https://ideone.com/L2p0GE).

Comment: @4castle But if you look closely at your output, you will see that there are duplicates, e.g. `- - +` and `+ - -` and `- + -` ... not sure if the OP cares about this, but just wanted to point this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you need to construct the new array with the operators and add it in the index starting from zero, also the maximum combination you will get is 64

```
    String[][] allOps = new String[64][3];
    int count = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
                allOps[count][0] = ops[x];
                allOps[count][1] = ops[y];
                allOps[count][2] = ops[z];
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(allOps));
```

With java8 streams

```
    String[] ops = new String[] { "+", "-", "*", "/" };
    List<String> opsList = Arrays.asList(ops);
    String[][] combinations = opsList.stream()
                                .flatMap(x -> opsList.stream().flatMap(y -> opsList.stream().map(z -> new String[] { x, y, z })))
                                .toArray(String[][]::new);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(combinations));
```

Combinations

```
[[+, +, +], [+, +, -], [+, +, *], [+, +, /], [+, -, +], [+, -, -], [+, -, *], [+, -, /], [+, *, +], [+, *, -], [+, *, *], [+, *, /], [+, /, +], [+, /, -], [+, /, *], [+, /, /], [-, +, +], [-, +, -], [-, +, *], [-, +, /], [-, -, +], [-, -, -], [-, -, *], [-, -, /], [-, *, +], [-, *, -], [-, *, *], [-, *, /], [-, /, +], [-, /, -], [-, /, *], [-, /, /], [*, +, +], [*, +, -], [*, +, *], [*, +, /], [*, -, +], [*, -, -], [*, -, *], [*, -, /], [*, *, +], [*, *, -], [*, *, *], [*, *, /], [*, /, +], [*, /, -], [*, /, *], [*, /, /], [/, +, +], [/, +, -], [/, +, *], [/, +, /], [/, -, +], [/, -, -], [/, -, *], [/, -, /], [/, *, +], [/, *, -], [/, *, *], [/, *, /], [/, /, +], [/, /, -], [/, /, *], [/, /, /]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a minor errors, changed your last ops[y] to ops[z] and change ur x=1 to x=0, y=1 to y=0, z=1 to z=0, this is because the array starts from 0-3 not 1-3 therefor now u will be able to see the combination with "+", marked answered if you find helpful.

> ```
> String[][] allOps = new String[27][3];
> int count = 1;
>
> String[] ops = new String[] {"+","-","*","/"};
> for (int x=0;x<4;x++) 
> { 
>     for (int y=0;y<4;y++)  
>     {
>         for (int z=0;z<4;z++)
>         {
>
>
>             System.out.println(ops[x] + " " + ops[y] + " " + ops[z] + " " + count);
>             count++;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I guess I never noticed that error. But could you help me with the second issue? How can I put each operator in a 2D array?

Comment: String[] ops = new String[] {"+","-","*","/"}; this is already a 2D array

Answer (score 0):

There 64 (4*4*4) combinations of arranging the four operators *, -, /, and + into 3 places. You need to change your code little bit here, your for loop starts with index 0 and then continue the loop. Here how, although not sure why you want 2D array

```
String[][] arrayOfCombination = new String[64][1];
    int count = 0;
    String[] ops = new String[] { "+", "-", "*", "/" };
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++) {

                arrayOfCombination[count][0] = ops[x] + " " + ops[y] + " " + ops[z];
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < 64; row++) {

        System.out.println(arrayOfCombination[row][0]);

    }
```

The better approach would be to use ArrayList as follows,

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();

//adding combinations
list.add("[" + ops[x] + " " + ops[y] + " " + ops[z] + "]");

//printing them
System.out.println(list);
```